# Assign same value to every line where condition is met for one line using case logic

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm looking to find all of the tracking numbers where one line meets a condition and then assign a value to every row of that tracking number. I'm currently doing this with case logic but only get halfway there without creating more statements. Looking for a clean single statement.

The sql below only gives me the the case value for the line where I'd want it for every line in the tracking number where it applied. I'd want it to assign that value to every row in the case statement.

```
select [Tracking_No] ,
CASE WHEN [Tracking_No] in
(Select distinct [Tracking_No] where ([Row_Value] like '%A%') Then '1'
WHEN [Tracking Number] in
(Select distinct [Tracking_No] where ([Row_Value] like '%B%') Then '2'
ELSE '' END as Description
from dwh.mytable
```

Looking for something similar to this:

| Tracking_No | Row_Value | Description |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 10 | B | 1 |
| 10 | C | 1 |
| 10 | A | 1 |
| 11 | Q | 2 |
| 11 | B | 2 |
| 11 | D | 2 |
| 12 | A | 1 |
| 12 | D | 1 |
| 12 | D | 1 |

Comment: T-SQL is used by several products including, but not limited to, Sybase, SQL Server and Azure Synapse. What (R)DBMS are you using?

Comment: @LArnu SQL Server

Comment: Sample data (as text) would be most helpful.

Comment: You'll need to either join the table to itself, use a nested query in the SELECT clause, or use an APPLY operation.

Comment: @JohnCappelletti  - Sorry, second post. New to all of this.  I adjusted the post to show a table. Not sure how to show as text

Comment: @JoelCoehoorn 
Ok. So I tried this and it appears to work however I'm not sure if this is the right approach since I'd always have to assign a blank value in order for the max function to work. 

'Select a.Tracking_No, b.Row_Value, Max(Description) from
(select Tracking_No,
CASE WHEN Tracking_No in
(Select distinct Tracking_No where (Row_Value like '%A%') Then '1'
WHEN [Tracking Number] in
(Select distinct Tracking_No where (Row_Value like '%B%') Then '2'
ELSE '' END as Description
from dwh.mytable) a
join dwh.mytable b on a.Tracking_No= b.Tracking_No'

Comment: Have you tried?

Comment: I show in the previous comment to yours what I've tried. Is there an additional suggestion I'd missed?

Answer (score 1):

You could perhaps try a windowed aggregate here

```
select *, 
    case 
        when Min(Row_Value) over(partition by Tracking_No) like '%A%' then '1'
        when Min(Row_Value) over(partition by Tracking_No) like '%B%' then '2'
    end [Description]
from t;
```